# RxSwift: How to create an observable using two other observables (one of which relies on the other)?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift and just inherited an old codebase (none of the original developers are around). I'm trying not to make many/any tweaks to the architecture (MVVM).

In the code, each view controller has a view model, and each view model exposes Rx Drivers that the view controllers can use to update their UI (genericized driver example below):

```
lazy var imageToDisplay: Driver<UIImage?> = {
        Observable.combineLatest(observableAPICall1(), observableAPICall2())
            .map { [unowned self] payload1, payload2 in
                if payload1 == nil || payload2 == nil {
                    return UIImage(named: "default")!
                } else {
                    return payload1.image
                }
            }
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: nil)
}()
```

Within the view model driver code, we make API calls via methods that return observables (ex: `observableAPICall1()` seen above).

For my current task, I'm adding a new API call that requires some information about the user before it can be called (let's say the API call is `getGiftIdeasForUser(givenBirthday: Date)` and the required info is the user's birthday).

Now, here's the part I'm struggling with: both the API call and the user's profile (the object that stores the birthday) are observables. So, how can I structure my code / API call to ensure I have the user's birthday before making said API call?

In other words, is there a way to chain things so that I get the user profile observable first, then hit the `getGiftIdeasForUser()` observable API after?

Apologies in advance if I'm thinking about this the wrong way ... still wrapping my head around Rx. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic solution would be something like this:

```
struct User {
    let birthday: Date
}
struct GiftIdea { }

func example(userProfile: Observable<User>, getGiftIdeasForUser: @escaping (Date) -> Observable<[GiftIdea]>) -> Observable<[GiftIdea]> {

    userProfile
        .map { $0.birthday }
        .flatMap { getGiftIdeasForUser($0) }

}
```

However, there are several different `flatMap` functions and the one you should use depends on context you didn't provide. Here is an article explaining the different `flatMap` operators and under what context you would use them in: [RxSwift's Many Faces of FlatMap](https://danielt1263.medium.com/rxswifts-many-faces-of-flatmap-5764e6c2018c)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the answer and link to the article, Daniel! You're the man.